# Editar .java para convertirlo en .class

Tags: java

Tengo que modificar un valor `Thread.sleep()` el cual no me deja editarlo en el .class, pero si me deja ejecutarlo en el .java, el problema es que cuando lo modifico y lo guardo no se me actualiza en el archivo .class correspondiente.

Comment: *editarlo en el .java

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, no añadas comentarios con más información. No puedes editar el .java para convertirlo en .class, ya que son cosas totalmente diferentes. Uno contiene código **Java**, el otro **Bytecode *"compilado"***. Lo que debes hacer es modificar tu archivo normal y luego usar el javac para generar el otro! Hay muchos tutoriales de cómo usar javac para generar los archivos `class`, o también puedes usar un IDE como netbeans o intelliJ que hacen todo ese trabajo por ti con un click.

Comment: puedes [edit] la pregunta para corregir lo que quieras, bienvenido a SOes

Comment: Entonces edito el .java y lo compilo con javac

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que edites tu archivo .java, luego lo compiles con javac para que te genere el .jar o .war, abras el .jar y extraigas el .class y luego lo pongas en tu .jar (war) que vas a ejecutar.

Comment: He compilado con javac usando el siguiente comando ```javac -sourcepath src/java/principal src/java/principal/WebServer.java -d target/classes/```

Comment: Y me salta el siguiente error 
src/java/principal/WebServer.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
            Notification notification = Main.db.getNotification(notificationId);
            ^
  symbol:   class Notification
  location: class WebServer
src/java/principal/WebServer.java:47: error: package Main does not exist
            Notification notification = Main.db.getNotification(notificationId);
                                            ^
src/java/principal/WebServer.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
            Client client = Main.db.getClient(notification.getClient_dni());